# send both attachment and template in single email with AWS(SES) in node

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, nest, amazon-ses

I want to send an email using AWS(SES) in nest js app. In that I want to send pdf attachment and html template in a single email. I searched for it but not succeeded to find a solution.
i found to method two methods in doc that are sendRawEmail and sendTemplatedEmail . currently using "sendTemplatedEmail" this one to send template email.
but i want to send both in a single email.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/SES.html#sendEmail-property